# How to force webrequest to not change my url string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http

I have a Url that is already url encoded and a hash is generated for the encoded part. I need to get the response of this url in server side, but the problem is webrequest is capitalize encoded parts of url so in the other side hashed url not verified.

the original url string is:

**/yonlendirme.aspx?action=create&name=Deneme%20Alt%20%c4%b0%c3%a7erik%20Oturumu%202&meetingID=baa4a6b1&moderatorPW=M97f15B7113G&attendeePW=Ow2D75JE160B&voiceBridge=73079&welcome=%25%25CONFNAME%25%25%27e+ho%c5%9fgeldiniz&logoutURL=http%3a%2f%2fidollive.idolyazilim.net&checksum=5ab4fe8ddf18385ceb1e5f035f0a2259d60f1fc4&CustCode=6d3bae161a&meetingS=1425298560&meetingE=1425309390**

and after initialize using webrequest.create function it turned to:

**/yonlendirme.aspx?action=create&name=Deneme%20Alt%20%C4%B0%C3%A7erik%20Oturumu%202&meetingID=baa4a6b1&moderatorPW=M97f15B7113G&attendeePW=Ow2D75JE160B&voiceBridge=73079&welcome=%25%25CONFNAME%25%25'e+ho%C5%9Fgeldiniz&logoutURL=http:%2f%2fidollive.idolyazilim.net&checksum=5ab4fe8ddf18385ceb1e5f035f0a2259d60f1fc4&CustCode=6d3bae161a&meetingS=1425298560&meetingE=1425309390**

the change in hex parts of url  ***(for example: Deneme%20Alt%20%c4%b0%c3%a7erik != Deneme%20Alt%20%C4%B0%C3%A7erik | or => logoutURL=http%3a%2f%2fidollive.idolyazilim.net != logoutURL=http:%2f%2fidollive.idolyazilim.net)***
prevent the verification phase of the app in the other api site.

so simply I want to force webrequest to not change casing of my url.

*Note: this behavior is only in .net 4.5 and in .net 4.0 I didn't have this problem.*

or is there any other way to call a http request in server side in c#

Comment: Given that either is legal (the escape codes can be either upper or lower case), I would suggest that the problem really lies at the other end, where the hashing should be run over the unescaped path.

Comment: @spender thank you for your reply, but that is not a solve, the other part just looks at your query string and tries to generate checksum again, and compares your sent check with it's generated one, and because of upper cases the checksomes will not equal.

Comment: @mesut You could instead first .ToUpper() or .ToLower() your URL, **then** hash it.

Comment: @GrawCube But it will change every things in the querystrings some of them needed to sent as is, for example: meeting name, welcome message and so